# How to store a variable that increments by the index?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm very new to programming and I was wondering how I could store and print the variables that are being incremented in bash.

```
#!/bin/bash
ethcounter=$(ifconfig -a | egrep --count "eth")
ethindex0=$((ethcounter-1))

echo ethindex0 = $ethindex0

for ((i=0; i<=ethindex0; i++))
 do
    eth[$i]=$(ifconfig eth$i)
    echo "eth[$i]" = "$eth[$i]"
 done
```

The end goal here is to store the IP address of each eth device I can see when I perform ifconfig.

```
eth0 = ifconfig eth0 ... IP address
eth1 = ifconfig eth1 ... IP address
```

I would need a way to manipulate the output of `ifconfig` in order to store the IP address as well. What is the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need much to do that, just declare `eth` variable as an array (and change the way it's accessed):

```
#!/bin/bash
ethcounter=$(ifconfig -a | egrep --count "eth[0-9]+")
ethindex0=$((ethcounter-1))
declare -a eth

echo ethindex0 = $ethindex0

for ((i=0; i<=ethindex0; i++))
 do
    eth[$i]=$(ifconfig eth$i)
    echo "eth[$i]" = "${eth[$i]}"
 done
```

I've also slightly tweaked your `egrep` parameter, cause it matched lines containing word 'ether'. Of course it probably needs more than that, but you can try finding out on your own.

As jordanm rightly noted in comments: don't assume that interfaces are sequentially numbered. You should rather `grep` out whatever you want, and process all the values that you've got, and store them in an associative array (indexed by interface names instead of numbers).

Side note: Interface can have more than one IP address. That, and `ifconfig` going into deprecation, might encourage you to use `ip` instead, especially `ip addr` - as this case is supported there.

Comment: `ifconfig` *is* deprecated, but it's unlikely to ever go away. The assumption that interfaces are always sequentially numbered is bad. That isn't your problem though as this answers OP's question.

Comment: @jordanm That's true, but it can't even deal with multiple IP adresses on my machine, unless I'm missing something. I should probably edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks @TNW! By declaring it as an array variable, it was able to index the variables properly.  Can you explain the why I need to use the { } for this particular line?  Why can't $eth[$i] as recognized as a value?

echo "eth[$i]" = "${eth[$i]}"

Comment: @WeSC With braces you mark where does your variable access start and end. Without them, `bash` tries to do equivalent of `${eth}[${i}]`. Using braces is a good practice almost everywhere, barring maybe positional arguments (`$0`, `$1`...), and they allow to do more things (see **Parameter expansion** in bash man page).

Comment: @TNW How would I export the variable "eth[$i]" to other subprocesses?  I want to be able to call this variable from other test scripts.